# Código Java para subir una imagen a Sybase

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Este código lo usé para subir una imagen a una base de datos Mysql sin embargo al querer usarlo con una base de datos Sybase me fue complicado hacerlo.

```
    public void ProcesarCaptura(DPFPSample sample) throws DPFPImageQualityException{

  // Procesar la muestra de la huella y crear un conjunto de caracteristicas con el proposito de inscripcion.
    featuresinscripcion = extraerCaracteristicas(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_ENROLLMENT);

    // Procesar la muestra de la huella y crear un conjunto de caracteristicas con el proposito de verificacion.
    featuresverificacion = extraerCaracteristicas(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_VERIFICATION);

    // Comprobar la calidad de la muestra de la huella y lo añade a su reclutador si es bueno


       try
    {
        System.out.println("Las Caracteristicas de la Huella han sido creada");
        Reclutador.addFeatures(featuresinscripcion);// Agregar las caracteristicas de la huella a la plantilla a crear

        // Dibuja la huella dactilar capturada.
        Image image=CrearImagenHuella(sample);
        //Declarar la variable con la imagen almacenada
        Ejemplo =  (BufferedImage) image;
        String formato = "JPEG";

        /**
         * Convierte una imagen en BufferedImage
         *
         * @param img La Image a convertir
         * @return El BufferedImage convertido
         */

          //Convertir a array de datos
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try 
    {
            ImageIO.write( Ejemplo, formato, out);
    }   catch (IOException ex) 
    {
            Logger.getLogger(Capturar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    }
        catch (DPFPImageQualityException ex) 
    {
        System.err.println("Error: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
       guardarHuella(null);
       Reclutador.clear();
        stop();
    }
        Consulta co = new Consulta();
        Conexion.mysqlConexion con = new mysqlConexion();
        public void guardarHuella(Usuario usuario) 
    {                  
        try 
    {
 //Establece los valores para la sentencia SQL

       conexion=mysqlConexion.Conexion();

            try (PreparedStatement guardarStmt = conexion.prepareStatement("UPDATE clientes SET ImagenIndiceIzq=?  WHERE identificacion ="+co.Identificar)) 
            {
                guardarStmt.setBinaryStream(1, in);
                //Ejecuta la sentencia
                guardarStmt.execute();
            }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Huella Guardada Correctamente");
       conexion.close();
       Reclutador.clear();
       stop();
       MiVentana.dispose();

    } 
        catch (SQLException ex)
    {
       //Si ocurre un error lo indica en la consola
       System.err.println("Error al guardar los datos de la huella.");
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La persona  se encuentra registrada por favor verificar los datos e intentar de nuevo ","VERIFICACION DE DATOS", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
        finally
    {
        try 
    {
           conexion.close();
    }
       catch (SQLException ex)
       {
           Logger.getLogger(Capturar.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }    
    }  
    }  
    }
```

que parte deberia corregir para poder subir la imagen en Sybase? iniciando por que en Mysql el tipo de campo es *Blob* y en Sybase es tipo *Image*

De antemano agradezco sus respuestas